# Proving the behavior of a function on symmetric domain

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

This is a problem I am stuck at. I think this problem has to do with Riemann mapping theorem and Schwarz reflection principle, but I cannot find a way to solve it... Could anyone please help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Look at $g \colon z \mapsto \overline{f(\overline{z})}$. What do you know about $g$?

Comment: All I can see is that $g$ is another analytic function. Could you tell me what I am missing?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880982/conformal-mapping-between-regions-symmetric-across-the-real-line) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884908/conformal-mapping-between-symmetric-region-and-unit-disc).